# select query with if

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

I have a column: account_type which contains four characters. `d`, `h`, `v`, `a`. Now, if the account_type is `d` then it should display `DBA`, if `a` then `application`, if `v` then `vendor`, and if `h` then `human`. I tried this query.

```
SELECT da.account_name, da.account_id,da.manager_lastname, da.manager_firstname, 
dap.live_password_change, dap.dev_password_change, das.status_desc, 
REPLACE(RTRIM(CONCAT(IF(da.account_type = 'd', 'DBAs', 'NO'))), ' ', ', ')
FROM dba_account da
LEFT JOIN dba_account_password dap ON da.account_id = dap.account_id
LEFT JOIN dba_account_status das ON da.status = das.status_id
WHERE CAST(da.account_name AS BINARY) RLIKE '[a-z]'
AND da.account_name NOT RLIKE '[#$\\\\////]'
ORDER BY da.account_name
```

But i dont know how to compare 4 conditions. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `CASE` similar to this:

```
    SELECT da.account_name, da.account_id,da.manager_lastname, da.manager_firstname, 
dap.live_password_change, dap.dev_password_change, das.status_desc, 
CASE da.account_type 
    WHEN 'd' THEN 'DBAs'
    WHEN 'a' THEN 'application'
    WHEN 'v' THEN 'vendor'
    WHEN 'h' then 'human' 
    ELSE 'NO' END as 'account_type'
FROM dba_account da
LEFT JOIN dba_account_password dap ON da.account_id = dap.account_id
LEFT JOIN dba_account_status das ON da.status = das.status_id
WHERE CAST(da.account_name AS BINARY) RLIKE '[a-z]'
AND da.account_name NOT RLIKE '[#$\\\\////]'
ORDER BY da.account_name
```

Comment: it says : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), ' ', ', ') FROM dba_account da LEFT JOIN dba_account_password dap ON da.accou' at line 1

Comment: @ashah142 see my edit, try it without the `REPLACE(RTRIM(CONCAT(` around it

Answer (score 1):

Try a [CASE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html). It works like `switch` in many languages.

Comment: hey i tried using case but it says syntax error. is there any way you can give me an example to follow? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement in SQL, your query would be rewritten like this:

```
SELECT 
    da.account_name, da.account_id,da.manager_lastname, da.manager_firstname, 
    dap.live_password_change, dap.dev_password_change, das.status_desc, 
    CASE da.account_type\
        WHEN 'd' THEN 'DBAs'
        WHEN 'v' THEN 'vendor'
        WHEN 'h' THEN 'human'
        ELSE 'unknown'
    END
FROM 
    dba_account da LEFT JOIN 
        dba_account_password dap ON da.account_id = dap.account_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    dba_account_status das ON da.status = das.status_id 
WHERE 
    CAST(da.account_name AS  BINARY) RLIKE '[a-z]' 
    AND da.account_name NOT RLIKE '[#$\\\\////]' 
ORDER BY 
    da.account_name;
```

For more info on the case statement in MySQL 5.6, you can visit here: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html